# What are best practices for "trimming" an exception stacktrace prior to logging with SLF4J?

Tags: java, exception, kotlin, slf4j

*Note: I'm coding in [Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/) but I think the answer will likely be the same for Kotlin or Java*

I am building [a web framework](https://github.com/sanity/kweb) in which I want to report errors to the user along with a stacktrace pertaining to where in the user's code the error is (it's a little complicated because the errors are actually JavaScript errors generated by a web browser that is being "remote controlled" by the web framework).

I can create a Throwable() however the stacktrace will have a lot of superfluous StackTraceElements from my framework code, both before and after the StackTraceElements relevant to the user of the code, like so:

```
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] ERROR com.github.sanity.kweb.KWeb - JavaScript error: 'Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation'
Caused by executing: '1++2':
        at com.github.sanity.kweb.KWeb.execute(KWeb.kt:136)
        at com.github.sanity.kweb.RootReceiver.execute(RootReceiver.kt:30)
        at com.github.sanity.kweb.dom.element.Element.execute(Element.kt:24)
        at com.github.sanity.kweb.demos.todo.TodoKt$main$1.invoke(todo.kt:15)
        at com.github.sanity.kweb.KWeb$2.invoke(KWeb.kt:63)
        at com.github.sanity.kweb.KWeb$2.invoke(KWeb.kt:28)
        at org.wasabifx.wasabi.protocol.http.HttpRequestHandler.runHandlers(HttpRequestHandler.kt:123)
        at org.wasabifx.wasabi.protocol.http.HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(HttpRequestHandler.kt:82)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:372)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:358)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:350)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:372)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:358)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:350)
        at org.wasabifx.wasabi.core.HttpPipelineInitializer.applyHttp1Pipeline(HttpPipelineInitializer.kt:72)
        at org.wasabifx.wasabi.core.HttpPipelineInitializer.initHttpPipeline(HttpPipelineInitializer.kt:51)
        at org.wasabifx.wasabi.core.HttpPipelineInitializer.channelRead0(HttpPipelineInitializer.kt:32)
        at org.wasabifx.wasabi.core.HttpPipelineInitializer.channelRead0(HttpPipelineInitializer.kt:17)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:372)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:358)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:350)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:372)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:358)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:350)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:372)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:358)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:350)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:372)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:358)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:610)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:551)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:465)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:437)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So I'm filtering the StackTraceElements to remove those not relevant to the user (mostly by filtering by class name and package), and then appending the stacktrace to a StringBuilder in the standard stacktrace format before logging it to SLF4J as a string (with line separator characters).

```
val disregardClassPrefixes = listOf(KWeb::class.jvmName, RootReceiver::class.jvmName, Element::class.jvmName, "org.wasabifx", "io.netty", "java.lang")
debugInfo.throwable.stackTrace
  .filter { ste -> ste.lineNumber >= 0 && !disregardClassPrefixes.any { ste.className.startsWith(it) } }
  .forEach { stackTraceElement ->
                logStatementBuilder.appendln("        at ${stackTraceElement.className}.${stackTraceElement.methodName}(${stackTraceElement.fileName}:${stackTraceElement.lineNumber})")
}
```

This gives us the much nicer:

```
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] ERROR com.github.sanity.kweb.KWeb - JavaScript error: 'Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation'
Caused by executing: '1++2':
        at com.github.sanity.kweb.demos.todo.TodoKt$main$1.invoke(todo.kt:15)
```

However, this approach smells somewhat kludgy and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The only valid answer is DON'T.

You cannot know in advance what parts of the stack trace are relevant, and if you remove or trim anything you may be removing the one piece of data that allows you to troubleshoot.

To repeat: DON'T DO IT. The stack trace is ugly but necessary. Also resist the urge to remove "Caused By" sections.  They are there for a reason and often contain the "real" exception.

Comment: You might be right in most scenarios, but I don't think this applies to this scenario because I'm the one throwing the exception from my own code, so I can indeed know in advance what parts of the stacktrace are relevant (as illustrated in the example I provided).

Comment: As a developer who has had to debug other people's code many times, I stand by my assertion that the entire stack trace is important.  But that's only my opinion from 20+ years of experience.

Comment: And mine is just my opinion from 20+ years of experience :/

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to catch the JavaScript error and throw a custom exception containing the message (or details to construct the message) you want the user to receive.